# HTML Get method

Tags: html

I have create a form with one text field and one select field and using GET method. Is it possible to make the parameter combine to one when submit the form? Example: test.html?domain=test.com

```
<form action = "test.html" method = "GET">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "domain" />
      <select name="domain_ext" class="inputAuto">
        <option value=".com">.com</option>
      </select>
     <input type = "submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: You can do this using javascript or jquery

Comment: Not without JS, and not need to prettify everything

Comment: Hi, can explain in more detail? cause i not familiar with JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use XHR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Here's a very basic example:

```js
var getData = function () {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var domain = document.querySelector('.domainInput').value;
  var ext = document.querySelector('.extInput').value;
  xhr.responseType = 'text';
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
      document.querySelector('.output').innerText = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', domain + ext, true);
  xhr.send(null);
};

document.querySelector('.getButton').addEventListener('click', getData);
```

```html
<form>
   Name: <input type="text" value="https://output.jsbin.com/juwuy" class="domainInput" />
    <select class="extInput">
      <option value=".js" default>.js</option>
      <option value=".com">.com</option>
    </select>
   <input type="button" value="Get" class="getButton"/>
</form>
<p class="output"></p>
```